# Compile Adobe Flash Builder project with Flex SDK command line

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, command-line, sdk

I have inherited a Flash Builder 4.6 project, but cannot get the Eclipse FB to compile the project, and now my 60 days has lapsed.

I got fed up with being sent in circles by Eclipse/Fb and now I want to try and sanitise/understand the process by building manually using Flex SDK 4.6.

Trouble, is I do not know where to start. There is the MXMLC.exe and CompC.exe, there are projects within the workspace with inter-depedencies.

Simple example using ANt exists where the chap is only compiling from a single source file.

In my workspace I have a main project folder with sub-folders like src containing .as, .mxml, .png files and sub0fodlers like "assets". At the src root folder there is the main mxml which maps to the final compiled exe.

The project also has a "libs", "bin" "bin-release" folder.

The referenced projects are similar.

One of the referenced projects is "flerry".

I want a single Windows Perl/BAT scipts that will compile this for me.

Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: If you have dependencies to manage, I'd rather go with a build tool like FlexMojos (a Maven plugin) or GradleFx (a Gradle plugin) than with a BAT script. It's a good idea to try to compile a project without dependencies through the CLI first though, to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

mxmlc.exe is used to compile the application, compc.exe is used to compile libraries. If you have code library dependencies, you'll first need to compile these and then compile your application.

The documentation on compiling is pretty good and can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcc.html

I would suggest you give this a go and post specific questions if you run into issues.